# How to set selection indicator on passing object Index in picker View

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I have 3 buttons on one View of UIViewController. On each button click event i called same picker view with different object values.

how to set the selection indicator on last object index for particular
button.?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)selectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component animated:(BOOL)animated
```

> Selects a row in a specified component of the picker view.

[Source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html)

Answer (score 0):

In button click event you can make use of this.

1. `selectRow:inComponent:animated:` - Helps you select particular row in the picker.
2. `numberOfRowsInComponent:` - Returns the count of rows in the particluar component.

So inorder to select the last object index, you can make use of this.

```
[self.pickerView selectRow:[self.pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:0] inComponent:0 animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using following snippet

```
[self.pickerView selectRow:MAX_VALUE inComponent:0 animated:NO];

where MAX_VALUE = total no. of rows in component - 1;
```

Enjoy Programming !!